# Aligning the textual tabular representaion in JTextArea

Tags: java, jtextarea, text-alignment

I am creating a `JTextArea` and appending some newline separated string to it.

It looks kind of aligned in a different way than how it actually looks like in the input string.

**JTextAreaDemo.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
 *
 * @author dinesh
 */
public class TextAreaDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input
                = "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
                + "| Name               | STC Port           | Tx Count (frames)  | Rx Count (frames)  | Tx Rate (fps)      | Rx Rate (fps)      | Tx Count (bits)    | Rx Count (bits)    | Tx Rate (bps)      | Rx Rate (bps) |    \n"
                + "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
                + "| vlan105            | 12/5               | 165                | 146                | 5                  | 5                  | 168960             | 149504             | 5120               | 5120 |             \n"
                + "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
                + "| vlan104            | 12/5               | 165                | 145                | 5                  | 5                  | 168960             | 148480             | 5120               | 5120 |             \n"
                + "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
                + "| vlan105            | 12/6               | 159                | 146                | 5                  | 5                  | 162816             | 144832             | 5120               | 4960 |             \n"
                + "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
                + "| vlan104            | 12/6               | 158                | 145                | 5                  | 5                  | 161792             | 143840             | 5120               | 4960 |             \n"
                + "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Text");
        JPanel pnlMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea();
        pnlMain.add(txtArea);
        txtArea.setEditable(false);
        myFrame.getContentPane().add(pnlMain);
        myFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        txtArea.append(input);
    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image: Java GUI Output]

As you can see, the alignment of the text looks different than the actual data.

**Actual data :**

```
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
"| Name               | STC Port           | Tx Count (frames)  | Rx Count (frames)  | Tx Rate (fps)      | Rx Rate (fps)      | Tx Count (bits)    | Rx Count (bits)    | Tx Rate (bps)      | Rx Rate (bps) |    \n"
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
"| vlan105            | 12/5               | 165                | 146                | 5                  | 5                  | 168960             | 149504             | 5120               | 5120 |             \n"
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
"| vlan104            | 12/5               | 165                | 145                | 5                  | 5                  | 168960             | 148480             | 5120               | 5120 |             \n"
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
"| vlan105            | 12/6               | 159                | 146                | 5                  | 5                  | 162816             | 144832             | 5120               | 4960 |             \n"
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
"| vlan104            | 12/6               | 158                | 145                | 5                  | 5                  | 161792             | 143840             | 5120               | 4960 |             \n"
"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

I have placed the string in such a way that each cell has 20 character width. But, It is started to deviate from the column-wise aspect.

What should I do to make it align accordingly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is occurring because of proportional-width fonts in your text area and fixed-width fonts in your code editor. It looks like what you really want here is a [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

If you really need a text area, I would recommend:

```
txtArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

This will make it display like it does in your code editor.

Comment: I am trying to print the textual tabular representation of the output value in the `JtextArea` which is a logger to a particular program.

Comment: I would recommend using a fixed-width font, then. I've modified my answer. `"monospaced"` will use the system default fixed-width font.